# Table row focus after refresh page jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have html table with some data (among other things link with get parameter) so when I click on that link page will refresh, and I need to get focus on selected row after that, can that be done with jQuery? Or somehow else?

Comment: It definitely can be done with jQuery. Give it a try and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: I dont know how :( That is why I asked.

Comment: When you click the link, get the index number of its parent tr. Save the index in a cookie. After page is refreshed, get the cookie value and you can highlight the row. Not sure what do you mean why you say focus the row.

Comment: My table is in div with scroll.So on page refresh scroll is back on top, and i need to get focus on selected row, not  first few...

Comment: I did it! :) if anyone has a similar problem here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/HwV96/3/